# Cannot add dependecies in pubspec.yaml without getting errors in flutter ios development

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

When on my Mac, and I try to add dependencies in the `pubspec.yaml` file I get an error saying

```
/Users/justindosaj/Desktop/Project Folder/testapp/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:10:9: fatal error: module 'firebase_admob' not found

    @import firebase_admob;

     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    1 error generated.

    note: Using new build system

    note: Planning build

    note: Constructing build description


Could not build the application for the simulator.

Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.



Exited (sigterm)
```

In this error it says can't find @import firebase_admob, but if I removed the firebase_admob from the pubspec file then it would give me the same error for the other 2 dependencies.

Flutter Doctor:

```
[flutter] flutter doctor -v
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.2 19C57, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at /Users/justindosaj/Desktop/ApplicationSoftware/flutter
    • Framework revision 27321ebbad (6 weeks ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/justindosaj/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /usr/bin/java
    ✗ Could not determine java version

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3.1, Build version 11C504
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 11 Pro Max • F64065AE-360F-474C-BC50-133614E7DC6A • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-3 (simulator)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
exit code 0
```

pubspec.yaml file:

```
name: testapp
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
  firebase_admob: ^0.9.0+10

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Runner' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Runner
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
end
```

Update: The ios simulator is able to run with the pods, but adding the dependencies in the pubspec.yaml still results in the same error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was cocoapods version 1.8+.

run

```
$sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

$sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.7.5

$pod setup
```

You also do not need to add anything to do your podfile if using flutter. Adding the dependencies in pubspec.yaml will automatically set up your podfile for you

Comment: I did this and I was unable to reinstall cocoapods. I got the error 
`While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.`
I'm now in a worse position than when I started